Will SEEK_SET SEEK_CUR SEEK_END not be 0,1,2 on any C lib?
For whence parameter of fseek (or lseek in POSIX), some languages that calls C lib assume SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END are 0,1,2, respectively, such as gfortran, Nim [^py].
[^py]: while Python's seek specializes concrete values of SEEK_*, CPython does map 0,1,2 to C lib's values internally.
I've looked up C and POSIX specialization, neither specializes  concrete values of SEEK_*.
In code, I wonder in which OS and C compiler, the following code's output isn't 012:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%d%d%d\n", SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END);
}

I've tested on some OSes and C compilers, where the output is just 012:

Windows: gcc(mingw), MSVC
Debian: clang, gcc
FreeBSD: clang
Solaris(SunOS5): Oracle Solaris Studio C Compiler
Android(Termux): clang

And if there're none, then it's less meaningful to add fix for the existing implementations using fixed values.

To clearify, I wonder if there is any C libraries/OSes whose SEEK_* values differ

Why does that matter? If you use the SEEK_* constants, the actual values should be irrelevant to you regardless of the library or OS. That's the entire reason those identifiers exist.

Because, as mentioned above, some langauges' implementation used fixed values instead of SEEK_*. I wonder if they'll fail on some libraries/OSes

And as I said, the values assigned to SEEK_* should not matter to you. If the SEEK_* defines don't exist, then clearly you'll have to use that language's fixed values instead. Asking us to provide a list of those languages isn't an appropriate use of this site.

"I wonder if they'll fail on some libraries/OSes", I'm just thinking if any C lib/OSes uses other values for SEEK_ macros

If they don't exist, your code won't compile for that platform. Again, this is something that should be irrelevant. Use the constants. If you try to compile against some libraries where those values don't exist, you'll get a compiler error. Otherwise, the values are safe to use.

Again, what the value is doesn't matter. And polling questions ("which OS and C compiler, the following code's output isn't 012") are off-topic here. When you have an actual issue, you can ask here.

Are you a maintainer of the mentioned languages? Assuming fixed values for those constants is certainly a quality of implementaion issue for the developers of those languages, but they're usually not what a user of those language should care about unless you come across some real bug. Also I'm surprised that you tested on Windows but have not included MSVC.

"Are you a maintainer of the mentioned languages": A contributor; "Also I'm surprised that you tested on Windows but have not included MSVC.": I once installed MSVC, but have uninstalled as it's too big. Anyway, I've tested it now via Python's ctypes.windll.msvcrt

@lit - A library (or language) is never 100% portable. If you haven't tested your code on an IBM mainframe, a Cray supercomputer, or one with 36-bit ints, it is just not going to work there. The value of SEEK_SET is a lot smaller problem than what is the format for a (possibly non-ASCII) filename for those systems.


Will SEEK_SET SEEK_CUR SEEK_END aren't 0,1,2 on any C lib?

Maybe.  Yet if not today, maybe tomorrow.

If you must use 0, 1, 2 in calling fseek(), use the number as an array index.
I doubt there is a real case where one must do so.
#include <stdio.h>
const int whence [] = { SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END };

int result = fseek(stream, 0, whence[2]);  // Go to the end


In the ideal instance, you would want to write a C program to create an include file for the constants for the language that does not have those constants defined.  e.g.
  #include <stdio.h> 

  int 
  main (int argc, char *argv []) 
  {
    printf ("INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SEEK_SET = %d, SEEK_CUR = %d, SEEK_END = %d\n", 
        SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END);
  }

I have no idea what fortran include files look like, this would need to be fixed.
In this particular instance, SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR and SEEK_END are well defined as 0, 1, and 2, and you aren't going to have a problem with them.
